# Returning highest values in row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with % values. I want to write a function that returns the names of the columns in succession for the highest % per row. For example:

Input dataframe:

```
Customer ID          Grapes        Oranges       Apples         Bananas     
12345                12.131        39.123        97.847         18.442
67890                11.111        1.111         100.000        40.941
```

Output dataframe:

```
Customer ID          Rec 1         Rec 2         Rec 3          Rec 4       ...
12345                Apples        Oranges       Bananas        Grapes
67890                Apples        Bananas       Grapes         Oranges
...
```

I want this function to work for N amount of rows and columns, as the dataframes are updated/appended to on a regular basis. Any ideas/built in functionality that can do this to some extent? Like an descending order method that goes by row?

Comment: can you include the code you've tried so far to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) if performance is important:

```
N = 4
df = df.set_index('Customer ID')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.columns[np.argsort(-df.values, axis=1)[:, :N]], 
                               index=df.index)

df1 = df1.rename(columns=lambda x: 'Rec {}'.format(x + 1))
print (df1)

              Rec 1    Rec 2    Rec 3    Rec 4
Customer ID                                   
12345        Apples  Oranges  Bananas   Grapes
67890        Apples  Bananas   Grapes  Oranges
```

---

```
N = 2
df = df.set_index('Customer ID')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.columns[np.argsort(-df.values, axis=1)[:, :N]], 
                               index=df.index)

df1 = df1.rename(columns=lambda x: 'Rec {}'.format(x + 1))
print (df1)

              Rec 1    Rec 2
Customer ID                 
12345        Apples  Oranges
67890        Apples  Bananas
```

**Details**:

```
print ((np.argsort(-df.values, axis=1)[:, :N]))
[[2 1 3 0]
 [2 3 0 1]]

print (df.columns[np.argsort(-df.values, axis=1)[:, :N]])
Index([['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Bananas', 'Grapes'],
       ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Grapes', 'Oranges']], dtype='object')
```

Comment: the only issue with this answer is that the column name id is shifted by 1 vs the desired output

Comment: Surely legends on SO for pandas ( Wen, jezrael, & jpp) :) glad you guys are here, sorry for off-topic comment

Comment: @akashkarothiya the worst is when you think you have an answer for a question and then the pro's show up and totally crush it. Better to wait around noon (EST) when they take a rest :)

Comment: @Yuca hahah, true!! If any pandas question appears, I immediately stop thinking solution because I know for sure Wen, jezrael, or jpp will appear any time and nailed it

Comment: @Yuca - Special for you renamed columns ;)

Comment: *senpai noticed me*

Answer (score 2):

Using `melt` with `pivot`

```
newdf=df.melt('CustomerID').sort_values(['value'],ascending=False)
newdf.assign(key=newdf.groupby(['CustomerID']).cumcount()+1).pivot(index='CustomerID',columns='key',values='variable')
Out[96]: 
key              1        2        3        4
CustomerID                                   
12345       Apples  Oranges  Bananas   Grapes
67890       Apples  Bananas   Grapes  Oranges
```

Comment: Surely legends on SO for pandas ( Wen, jezrael, & jpp) :) glad you guys are here, sorry for off-topic comment

Comment: @akashkarothiya thank you man , they are the legends Jez ,coldspeed and jpp, I learn a lot from them

Comment: Your Welcome :) and now we are learning from you guys. Cheers!!